# How can I make these typedefs work?

Tags: c++

These lines are in different header files and end up getting included in a source file in the following order:

```
class Alice;

/* pointers to Alice declared here!! */

template<class T>
class Bob;

typedef Bob<int> Alice;

template<class T>
class Bob
{
};
```

VS2013 `error C2371: 'Alice' : redefinition; different basic types`

Why is this an error?
Any way to work around it?

Comment: Use different namespaces?

Comment: @ForEveR Is that a suggestion or a question?

Comment: first Alice is a class and 2nd  Alice is a template. probable that's why it is throwing error. My question is why you need this type of definition. you can rename any of Alice.

Answer (score 3):

It's ill-formed to declare something both as a class and as a typedef for a different class. Although class names and typedef names are interchangeable in many contexts, they are not always, e.g. it is possible to refer to the type as either `Alice` or `class Alice` (using what is called an *elaborated-type-specifier*) when it is a class, but that is not valid if `Alice` is a typedef name. That rule originates with C, where you can *only* use the elaborated-type-specifier and must declare a separate typedef to be able to say simply `Alice`.

The difference is important because the type has a "name for linkage purposes" which is the name used for name-mangling, which affects the symbols the linker sees.

If one file only saw the typedef name `Alice` and used that for the mangled name of a function such as `void foo(Alice*)` then you would not be able to link that function with other references to `void foo(Bob<int>*)` even though they should have the same mangled name.

For that reason it is necessary for the compiler to distinguish between typedefs (which are just aliases) and a type's "true name" (i.e. its name for linkage purposes).

The only workaround is to declare the types properly, so that the declaration of `Alice` as a typedef is used everywhere, i.e. replace the untrue `class Alice;` declaration with:

```
template<class T> class Bob;
typedef Bob<int> Alice;
```

Comment: template<class T> class Bob { };
typedef Bob<int> Alice;

Comment: @Clearer, you don't need to define `Bob` in order to be able to declare the `Alice` typedef, you only need to declare it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Absolutely true.

Answer (score 1):

you can use inheritance as a possible workaround:

```
class Alice;

Alice* a1;

template<typename T>
class Bob {};

class Alice : public Bob<int> {} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I assume this is right and  there is statement

```
Alice obj;
```

How compiler will interpret the "Alice". In symbol table there would be 2 entry: one as a class and other as a template.

That's why it is giving error.